# Segmentation fault using unordered_map unordered_set on recursive function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, recursion, unordered-map

I'm relatively new programming c++. I'm implementing a tree like index for a db using unorderd_map on the implementation of the tree data structure to store the children nodes. As im working with tree like structures the construction an search methods are recursive, also i store the pointers of the nodes, so i suspect i may have a sort of not well handled memory issue. I'm getting a segmentation fault. Next is my code and the output of it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "aux_functions.cpp"
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


class TreeLikeIndex
{
  public:
    TreeLikeIndex(string attribute, string indices, int indices_count, short int is_leaf, unordered_map<string, TreeLikeIndex*> children);
    TreeLikeIndex(string indices, int indices_count);
    TreeLikeIndex();
    string search(unordered_map<string, string> *);
  private:
     string indices;
     int indices_count;
     short int is_leaf;
     string attribute;
     unordered_map<string, TreeLikeIndex*> children;

};


string TreeLikeIndex::search(unordered_map<string, string> * _tuple)
{
  if((*_tuple).empty() || this->is_leaf ) return this->indices;
  string att_val = (*_tuple)[this->attribute];  
  (*_tuple).erase(this->attribute);
  TreeLikeIndex * child_with_that_value = this->children[att_val];
  return (*child_with_that_value).search(_tuple);
}



class DecisionTreeLikeIndexer
{

 public:
    DecisionTreeLikeIndexer(string, string, string);
    int rebuild_index();   
    TreeLikeIndex * get_index();

 private:
    TreeLikeIndex * build_index(unordered_set<string> attributes_list, int depth, string comma_separated_ids, int ids_list_count);
    TreeLikeIndex * index;
    string source_db_address;
    string dest_folder_address;
    time_t time_of_last_build;
    unordered_set<string> columns_names;
    string source_table_name;
    unordered_set<string> temp_tables_names;
    string id_column_name;
    sqlite3 * source_db_connection;
    int table_count;
};

int DecisionTreeLikeIndexer::rebuild_index()
{
  this->index = this->build_index(this->columns_names, 0, "", 0);
  this->time_of_last_build = time(NULL);
  return 0;
}

TreeLikeIndex *  DecisionTreeLikeIndexer::get_index()
{
  return this->index; 
}

DecisionTreeLikeIndexer::DecisionTreeLikeIndexer(string source_db_address, string table_name, string dest_folder_address)
{
  this->source_db_address = source_db_address;
  this->dest_folder_address = dest_folder_address;
  this->columns_names = Aux::get_column_names(source_db_address, table_name); 
  this->source_table_name = table_name;
  this->id_column_name = "rowid";
  this->source_db_connection = Aux::get_db_connection(this->source_db_address);

  // Getting count of this table

  sqlite3_stmt* statement;
  string query = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + this->source_table_name + ";";
  if(sqlite3_prepare(this->source_db_connection, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
    int res = sqlite3_step(statement);
    const unsigned char * count_char = sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);
    if(res == SQLITE_ROW)
     {
      stringstream _temp;
      _temp << count_char;
      _temp >> this->table_count;      
     }
     sqlite3_finalize(statement);     
   }
  else
   {
    cout <<  "Error initializating Indexer (Getting initial table count): " << sqlite3_errmsg(this->source_db_connection) << endl;
   }

}

TreeLikeIndex *  DecisionTreeLikeIndexer::build_index(unordered_set<string> attributes_list, int depth, string comma_separated_ids, int ids_list_count)
{

  if( attributes_list.size() <=1 || (depth > 0 && ids_list_count <= 1))
   {
     Aux::tabs(depth);
     cout << "Leaf at depth: " << depth << " Ids are: " << comma_separated_ids << " Ids count: " << ids_list_count << endl; 
     static TreeLikeIndex * node = new TreeLikeIndex((string)comma_separated_ids, (int)ids_list_count);
     return node;
   }

  string source_table = this->source_table_name;
  int count = this->table_count;

  if(depth > 0)
  {
    while(1)
    {
     source_table = *Aux::get_random_list_of_strings(1).begin();
     if(this->temp_tables_names.insert(source_table).second) break;
    }

    const string create_temp_table_stmnt = "CREATE TEMP TABLE " + source_table + " AS SELECT * FROM " + this->source_table_name + " WHERE " + this->id_column_name + " IN(" + comma_separated_ids + ")";  
    sqlite3_exec(this->source_db_connection, create_temp_table_stmnt.c_str(),Aux::sqlt_callback,0,NULL);
    count = ids_list_count;
    Aux::tabs(depth);
    cout << "Not root node" << endl; 
  }

  Aux::tabs(depth);
  cout << "Source table is: " << source_table << " Table count is: " << count << endl;
  Aux::tabs(depth);
  cout << "Attributes list is: "; for_each(attributes_list.begin(), attributes_list.end(),[](string v){cout << v << " ";}); 
  cout << endl; 
  const double E = log2(count) ;
  Aux::tabs(depth);
  cout << "Entropy of node: " << E << endl;
  string best_attribute;
  double best_gain;
  unordered_set<string> best_attribute_values;

  for(string attr: attributes_list)
  { 
    Aux::tabs(depth+1);
cout << "Analysing attribute: " << attr << endl;
const string get_at_count_values_query = "SELECT " + attr + ", count(" + attr + ") FROM " + source_table + " GROUP BY " + attr + ";";
    sqlite3_stmt * stmnt;
    double weighted_entropy = 0;
    unordered_set<string> this_att_values;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(this->source_db_connection, get_at_count_values_query.c_str(), -1, &stmnt, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      for(;;)
      {


       int res = sqlite3_step(stmnt);

       if(res == SQLITE_DONE || res==SQLITE_ERROR)
       {
        double gAti = E - weighted_entropy;
        Aux::tabs(depth+1);
        cout << "Finish computing WE for att: " << attr << " Gain is: " << gAti << endl;
        if(gAti > best_gain)
         {
          Aux::tabs(depth+1);
          cout << "Found attribute with better gain." << endl;
          best_gain = gAti;
          best_attribute = attr;
          best_attribute_values.clear();

         Aux::tabs(depth+1);
         for(string v:this_att_values)
          {
           best_attribute_values.insert(v);  
          }
          cout << endl;

          this_att_values.clear();
         }
       sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
       //delete &res; 
       break;
       }
       if(res == SQLITE_ROW)
       {

        string val = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmnt,0)));
        int vSize = sqlite3_column_int(stmnt,1);
        Aux::tabs(depth+2);
        this_att_values.insert(val);
        double ratio = double(vSize) / double(count);
        weighted_entropy += double(ratio) * double(log2(vSize));
        Aux::tabs(depth+2);
        cout << "Processing value: " << val << " With vSize: " << vSize << " Current WE is: " << weighted_entropy << endl;
      }
    }
  }
 }

  Aux::tabs(depth);
  cout << "Finish processing attributes list. Best attribute is: " <<     best_attribute << " Best gain is: " << best_gain << endl;
  Aux::tabs(depth);
  cout << "Best attribute values are: ";     for_each(best_attribute_values.begin(), best_attribute_values.end(), [](string v){cout << v << ",";}); cout << endl; 
  unordered_map<string, TreeLikeIndex *> children;
  for(string val: best_attribute_values)
  {

    const string get_ids_of_bestatt_val = "SELECT rowid FROM " + source_table + " WHERE " + best_attribute + " = " + val + ";";
    int ids_count = 0;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmnt;
    string ids = "";
    bool first = 1;
    int next_depth = depth + 1;
    unordered_set<string> next_attributes_set;

    for(string attr: attributes_list) if(attr != best_attribute) next_attributes_set.insert(attr);

    if(sqlite3_prepare(this->source_db_connection, get_ids_of_bestatt_val.c_str(), -1, &stmnt,0) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
       for(;;)
        { 
         int res = sqlite3_step(stmnt);

         if(res == SQLITE_ROW)
          {
            string id = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmnt,0)));
            if(!first) ids += "," + id;
            else ids += id;
            ids_count++;

          }

         if(res == SQLITE_DONE || res == SQLITE_ERROR)
          {
           Aux::tabs(depth+1);
           cout << "Adding branch for val: " << val << endl;
           Aux::tabs(depth+1);
           cout << " Next attributes are: ";     for_each(next_attributes_set.begin(), next_attributes_set.end(), [](string v){cout << v << ",";});
           cout << " Depth is: " << next_depth << " Ids are: " << ids << " Ids count: " << ids_count << endl;
           sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
           static TreeLikeIndex * temp_child =  this->build_index(next_attributes_set, next_depth, ids, ids_count);
           pair<string, TreeLikeIndex*> child (val, temp_child);
       children.insert(child);
          }
        }
     }
  }

  Aux::tabs(depth);
  cout << "Finish processing node, will return." << endl;
  static TreeLikeIndex * no_leaf_node = new TreeLikeIndex(best_attribute, "all", count, 0, children);
  return no_leaf_node;

}
}

TreeLikeIndex::TreeLikeIndex(std::string attribute, std::string indices, int indices_count, short int is_leaf, unordered_map<std::string, TreeLikeIndex*> children) 
{
  this->attribute = attribute;
  this->indices = indices;
  this->is_leaf = is_leaf;
  this->children = children; 
  this->children.clear();
  for(pair<string, TreeLikeIndex*> p: children) this->children.insert(p);
  this->indices_count = indices_count; 
}

TreeLikeIndex::TreeLikeIndex(string indices, int indices_count)
{
   this->indices = indices;
   this->indices_count = indices_count; 
   this->is_leaf = 1;
}

TreeLikeIndex::TreeLikeIndex()
{
   this->indices = "";
   this->indices_count = 0; 
   this->is_leaf = 1;
}




int main()
{

string source_db_address = "my_table";
string table_name = "b";
string dest_folder_address = ".";

DecisionTreeLikeIndexer indexer(source_db_address, table_name, dest_folder_address);
indexer.rebuild_index();
}
```

And the output is:

```
Source table is: b Table count is: 9
Attributes list is: cant_n_dec cant_n_des cant_n_control 
Entropy of node: 3.16993
    Analysing attribute: cant_n_dec
                    Processing value: 1 With vSize: 1 Current WE is: 0
                    Processing value: 2 With vSize: 4 Current WE is: 0.888889
                    Processing value: 3 With vSize: 2 Current WE is: 1.11111
                    Processing value: 4 With vSize: 1 Current WE is: 1.11111
                    Processing value: 5 With vSize: 1 Current WE is: 1.11111
    Finish computing WE for att: cant_n_dec Gain is: 2.05881
    Found attribute with better gain.

    Analysing attribute: cant_n_des
                    Processing value: 1 With vSize: 2 Current WE is: 0.222222
                    Processing value: 2 With vSize: 4 Current WE is: 1.11111
                    Processing value: 3 With vSize: 2 Current WE is: 1.33333
                    Processing value: 5 With vSize: 1 Current WE is: 1.33333
    Finish computing WE for att: cant_n_des Gain is: 1.83659
    Analysing attribute: cant_n_control
                    Processing value: 1 With vSize: 2 Current WE is: 0.222222
                    Processing value: 2 With vSize: 3 Current WE is: 0.750543
                    Processing value: 3 With vSize: 3 Current WE is: 1.27886
                    Processing value: 5 With vSize: 1 Current WE is: 1.27886
    Finish computing WE for att: cant_n_control Gain is: 1.89106
Finish processing attributes list. Best attribute is: cant_n_dec Best gain is: 2.05881
Best attribute values are: 1,2,3,4,5,
    Adding branch for val: 1
     Next attributes are: cant_n_control,cant_n_des, Depth is: 1 Ids are: 3 Ids count: 1
    Leaf at depth: 1 Ids are: 3 Ids count: 1
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: And when you stepped through your code, line by line, with your debugger, which line caused the segmentation fault, according to the debugger, and what did the stack trace look like?

Comment: I'm using prints(cout <<) as debuging technique. The program execution enters into a recursive context one step from the first(initial) one and returns a pointer( to a leaf node). This pointer is to be stored into a unordered_map while in the first(initial) context using insert. Is something like: T * obj = recursive_call(); some_pair("key", obj); uMap.insert(some_pair); There is where it crashes.

Comment: Putting extra print statements is completely insufficient for all but the most simplest of bugs. Learning and knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. The information available from a debugger is infinitely more useful than rudimentary print statements. Put this program aside, and spend some time learning to use a debugger.

Comment: That's true i'm not too handy at debugging C++ code. I tried to debug with Code::Blocks, it seems like the problem is with the sqlite3_step statement. Maybe it looses the reference to sqlite3_stmt * object when it move among contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not shure but....

I think the problem can be in the following cycle

```
   for(;;)
    { 
     int res = sqlite3_step(stmnt);

     if(res == SQLITE_ROW)
      {
        string id = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmnt,0)));
        if(!first) ids += "," + id;
        else ids += id;
        ids_count++;

      }

     if(res == SQLITE_DONE || res == SQLITE_ERROR)
      {
       Aux::tabs(depth+1);
       cout << "Adding branch for val: " << val << endl;
       Aux::tabs(depth+1);
       cout << " Next attributes are: ";     for_each(next_attributes_set.begin(), next_attributes_set.end(), [](string v){cout << v << ",";});
       cout << " Depth is: " << next_depth << " Ids are: " << ids << " Ids count: " << ids_count << endl;
       sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
       static TreeLikeIndex * temp_child =  this->build_index(next_attributes_set, next_depth, ids, ids_count);
       pair<string, TreeLikeIndex*> child (val, temp_child);
   children.insert(child);
      }
    }
```

I don't understand when terminate (no exit conditions in the `for(;;)`, no `return`'s and no `break`'s in the block).

And I suspect that che segmentation fault is caused by the following instruction

```
 int res = sqlite3_step(stmnt);
```

when, after the `SQLITE_DONE` or `SQLITE_ERROR` case (whith a call to

```
 sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
```

), the cycle is iterated again, with a `stmnt` invalid.

The following can be a solution?

```
if ( sqlite3_prepare(this->source_db_connection, get_ids_of_bestatt_val.c_str(), -1, &stmnt,0) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
   while ( sqlite3_step(stmnt) == SQLITE_ROW )
    {
      ids += ( first ? "" : "," )
         + std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmnt,0)));
      ids_count++;
    }

   Aux::tabs(depth+1);
   cout << "Adding branch for val: " << val << endl;
   Aux::tabs(depth+1);
   cout << " Next attributes are: ";
   for_each(next_attributes_set.begin(), next_attributes_set.end(), [](string v){cout << v << ",";});
   cout << " Depth is: " << next_depth << " Ids are: " << ids << " Ids count: " << ids_count << endl;
   sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
   static TreeLikeIndex * temp_child =  this->build_index(next_attributes_set, next_depth, ids, ids_count);
   pair<string, TreeLikeIndex*> child (val, temp_child);
   children.insert(child);
 }
```

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot, don't know how i didn't see that.